# Pronunciation of "signora" - [o], [o̞] or [ɔ]

Tags: regional, pronunciation

[Word Reference](https://www.wordreference.com/iten/signora), [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/signora#Pronunciation) and [dipi](http://www.dipionline.it/dizionario/ricerca?lemma=signora) say that "signora" is pronounced [siɲˈɲora] (Standard Italian), but I hear [ɔ] instead of [o] in the audios in the first two references. It doesn't sound at all the [o] I hear in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPA_vowel_chart_with_audio (and the Italian vowel trapezoid in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_phonology#Vowels confirms that Italian's /o/ is pronounced in the same height of [o]). The only place where I found the standard pronunciation was in [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=it&tl=en&text=signora). Am I mishearing the word or is there some inconsistency between the audio files and the corresponding IPA transcriptions which are not covered by these dictionaries?

Comment: There are regional variations. The “official” (Tuscan) pronunciation is with [o], but you can easily hear [ɔ]. See    http://www.dizionario.rai.it/poplemma.aspx?lid=14044&r=20396

Comment: That said, to my Italian ears the O's in both the audio samples sound closed.

Comment: I agree with egreg, and I'd add that dipi and DOP can be trusted as sources for _standard_ Italian (and in some cases alternate ones too), keeping in mind that regional variation in pronunciation is extreme.

Comment: Signòra is quite dialectal, is tipical of the center of Italy

Comment: @OldManofAran so the O in both audios sound like the one in https://www.wordreference.com/fren/eau to you? I wonder if other native Italian speakers hear the same.

Comment: @asdru so you're saying that people in Rome say [siɲˈɲɔra] ? I'm asking specifically about Rome because it's the accent I'm most interested in.

Comment: I don't know about the rest of Central Italy, but I'm from Rome and we use a /o/ (“closed o”) here.

Comment: @AlanEvangelista I guess nobody else actually listened to the two samples :) To give you an idea, in this famous sketch [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sp1vjc3L1r0] you can hear (second 6) the word "ignora" (/iɲˈɲɔra/ , verb "ignorare"). Does this o sound the same as the one in your examples to you?

Comment: @OldManofAran It sounds very similar. Maybe "signora" has an [o̞] instead of an [ɔ]  (it's hard for me to distinguish both), but it certainly doesn't sound the [o] (closed O) I'm used to, as in the French word "eau". Have you listened to that link I posted above with the pronunciation of "eau"? Does it sound exactly as the O in "signora" for you?

Comment: @AlanEvangelista it's maybe even closer, but the three of them for me are "ó", in opposition with the "ò" in the video.

Comment: Clearly it's not black/white (that's why I said italian ears), the "mapping" of a sound to a phoneme depends of my mother tongue and to what I'm used to distinguish. But for me the border between  "ó" and "ò" is definitely between the "signora" samples and the "ignora" video.

Comment: Indeed, apparently, Alan is talking mainly about phones and @OldManofAran about Italian phonemes.